# While publishing a project, how can I do input files "not reachable"?

Tags: c#, winforms, publishing

I have a c# winform project that I have a Data Folder where I read required documents from here.

While form is loading, I read documents from that location as seen code.

After publishing, these folders must be in programme document. I do not want user to reach that folder.

I do not want to cyrpt files. Can you give me any suggestions?

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public string root = Application.StartupPath + "\\datafolder";

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Requiredfiles RF = new Requiredfiles();
        RF.loadfiles(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use that path if you don't want users to modify the data there. Windows has several well-known locations where applications can store per-machine or per-user data, accessible through the `Environment.GetFolder` method and defined in the [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) enum, eg `ApplicationData` is user-specific while `CommonApplicationData` is for all users.

Comment: `I do not want user to reach that folder.` what kind of protection do you want? Against accidental modification? Protection from other users on the same machine? Encryption? Putting stuff in the data folders avoids accidental modifications, or having multiple applications mangle each other's data. It doesn't prevent the user from going into `C:\ProgramData` and locating the files though.

Comment: The only way to make the files "unavailable" to the user other than through your program is to obfuscate location, or some form of encoding, you may call it encryption though you probably don't need to use an actual strong encryption method. Either way, since your program should be able to open these documents, *the user will have access to them*, so you can only make life difficult for the user, not impossible. In short, there is no way to protect these files in such a way that the program has access to them but the user does not, unless you store them on a different server.

Comment: See the [IsolatedStorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile) class. Another way, is to keep all the files in a compressed achive, tamper with archive header, making it unreadable by common compression utilities. Restore the header when you need to read (in memory) a file.

Comment: You app will literally run with the privileges of the users so wherever you put the file it will be reachable. The only 2 solutions are encryption or put the file somewhere on a web server and not the user computer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you to add your input files as Resources in your project.

Then change this file property "Build action" to "Embedded Resource". It will be included in the exe file.

To access the file from yout code :  Properties.Resources.{filename}

Comment: Data files are definitely not resources. Even if they are available during compile time, they should be packaged as *content* not resources. In most cases though data files are provided by the end users at runtime